# DLLs won't register under 32-bit or 64-bit. How do I register them?

Tags: dll, regsvr32

I've copied my dlls into both C:\windows\System32 and C:\windows\SysWoW64, and have executed regsvr32.exe into both of them, and have ended up with an error message telling me that name.dll may be incompatible and that I should try registering under the other folder.

Side note: I am running cmd as an administrator. I have Windows 7, 64-bit OS. 
Edit: Also, I have confirmed that the dlls are 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

Is your DLL a COM DLL
The Regsvr32 Tool (regsvr32.exe) is used to register or un–register a COM DLL.
[Regsvr32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859484.aspx)

Comment: How do I tell? I received it from a company, should I ask them?

Comment: That would help.  It would also help if you provide some details on what you are trying to do with the DLL